# include full latex document into another latex document

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I like to draw picture in a full latex document then insert it into another LaTeX document. I wish to just use \input command to include the whole document rather than to insert the Ti*k*Z related preamable to main document and insert `tikzpicture` code into the other place.

for example, main document is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Test document
  \input{tikz.tex}
\end{document}
```

The `tikz.tex` content is:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you want to do this? it's possible as the answer shows but it replaces what should be a trivial `\input` command by a very fragile and invasive mechanism that tries to support skipping over the preamble of the included document. It would be much much simpler to input the tikz directly.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
\usepackage{standalone,tikz}
```

to the preamble of the main document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone,tikz}
\begin{document}
  Test document
  \input{tikz}
\end{document}
```

If you really wish to avoid adding `\usepackage{tikz}` to the main document, you can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  Test document
  \input{tikz}
\end{document}
```

In that case, consult the documentation for options you may need in case of conflicts.